# Getting data from model to view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, deployd

I'm not able to show the model data using this code,

```
App.PupilRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        dpd.workwork.get({by: params}, function(result, error) {
            return result;
        });
    }
});
```

.

```
this.resource('pupil', { path: 'pupil/:id' })
```

.

```
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="one wide column"></div>
    <div class="fourteen wide column">
        <div class="ui stacked segment">
                       {{#each model}}data{{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the 'return' in the model gives an array, ( [{"data":"data}] )

Can you see what I am doing wrong. I'm still new to Ember so it's a high possibillity of some huge error I made.

Comment: How `dpd.workwork.get` works it sends a ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

The model hook is expected to return a value - either the model itself or a promise.